# Create a view called emp_sal on the emp table by selecting the following fields

Tags: mysql

```
/* Create a view called emp_sal on the emp table by selecting the following fields in the order of highest salary to the lowest salary.

emp_no, first_name, last_name, salary */

CREATE TABLE  emp  (
   emp_no  int(11) NOT NULL,
   birth_date  date NOT NULL,
   first_name  varchar(14) NOT NULL,
   last_name  varchar(16) NOT NULL,
   gender  enum('M','F') NOT NULL,
   hire_date  date NOT NULL,
   salary  float(8,2) DEFAULT 7850.00
) ;

INSERT INTO  emp  VALUES 
(10001,'1953-09-02','Georgi','Facello','M','2020-02-23',7850.00),
(10002,'1964-06-02','Bezalel','Simmel','F','2020-02-23',1756.50),
(10003,'1959-12-03','Parto','Bamford','M','2020-02-23',7850.00),
(10004,'1954-05-01','Chirstian','Koblick','M','2020-04-15',3475.00),
(10005,'1955-01-21','Kyoichi','Maliniak','M','2019-12-27',1756.50),
(10006,'1953-04-20','Anneke','Preusig','F','2020-02-23',7850.00),
(10007,'1957-05-23','Tzvetan','Zielinski','F','2020-02-23',7850.00),
(10008,'1958-02-19','Saniya','Kalloufi','M','1994-09-15',6759.00),
(10009,'1952-04-19','Sumant','Peac','F','2020-02-23',7850.00),
(10010,'1963-06-01','Duangkaew','Piveteau','F','2019-12-27',1375.00),
(10011,'1953-11-07','Mary','Sluis','F','1990-01-22',6759.00),
(10012,'1960-10-04','Patricio','Bridgland','M','1992-12-18',3475.00),
(10013,'1963-06-07','Eberhardt','Terkki','M','2020-02-23',7850.00),
(10014,'1956-02-12','Berni','Genin','M','2020-02-23',1756.50),
(10015,'1959-08-19','Guoxiang','Nooteboom','M','2019-12-27',1375.00),
(10016,'1961-05-02','Kazuhito','Cappelletti','M','1995-01-27',3475.00),
(10017,'1958-07-06','Cristinel','Bouloucos','F','1993-08-03',6759.00),
(10018,'1954-06-19','Kazuhide','Peha','F','2020-02-23',7850.00),
(10019,'1953-01-23','Lillian','Haddadi','M','1999-04-30',7850.00),
(10020,'1952-12-24','Mayuko','Warwick','M','1991-01-26',4300.00),
(10021,'1960-02-20','Ramzi','Erde','M','2020-02-23',7850.00),
(10022,'1952-07-08','Shahaf','Famili','M','1995-08-22',7850.00),
(10023,'1953-09-29','Bojan','Montemayor','F','2020-02-23',1756.50),
(10024,'1958-09-05','Suzette','Pettey','F','1997-05-19',3475.00),
(10025,'1958-10-31','Prasadram','Heyers','M','2019-12-27',1375.00),
(10026,'1953-04-03','Yongqiao','Berztiss','M','1995-03-20',6759.00);



SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    emp_no,
    first_name,
    last_name,
   salary,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_no ORDER BY salary DESC) AS emp_sal
  FROM Emp
  INNER JOIN Dept ON first_name = last_name
)
WHERE DeptSalRank = 1
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking for a bit of help with your homework. Beginners are welcome, but we expect a good faith attempt at an answer from you first. 
Although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: _Nudge in the right direction_ https://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: You have a syntax error in the published query - you need to alias the sub query. Also publishing sample data from dept would hep us debug.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).